# Increment version number in versioninfo during tfsbuild

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012, tfsbuild, tfs-alerts

I am currently configuring my [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 4.5 solution in the [TFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) Build 2010. I am working with Visual Studio.

I have a versioninfo.cs file as part of my solution. How can I set this up to increment the version number in it during the build process? What change do I need to make to my build definition for this?

Answer (score 3):

What is versioninfo.cs in your implementation?

The way I typically do automatic versioning is to use the Community TFS Build Extensions TfsVersion activity: http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20TfsVersion%20build%20activity&referringTitle=Documentation

I usually use the format: Major.Minor.YYMM.DDRR  where Major/Minor are passed as arguments via the Build definition and manually incremented.  YY/MM/DD/RR are the year-month-day-revision that allows me to know which specific build/source was used to create an assembly given it's version #.

If you have multiple branches/builds that you want to distinguish between based on the assembly version alone you may need to tweak your version numbering scheme slightly to include some kind of branch identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this answer to Stack Overflow question *Working automatic build increment Visual Studio addin*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15733269/505539).

This is a free independent stand-alone tool named [ProjectBuildCounter](http://build.codeplex.com) which I hope is what you're looking for.