# Working automatic build increment Visual Studio addin

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, build-numbers

I'm searching for a **working** [Visual Studio 2012](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2012) addin which automatically increments my build number. Something like http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/. But this isn't working for me.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, if it matters.

Comment: Did the built-in auto-increment functionality not work for you?

Comment: @GaTechThomas -- Which "built-in" auto-increment functionality? I know of none that's useful.  There's a weird "feature" that lets you put "*"s in ONE of your Version strings and it puts in a 6+ digit build date (which is useless for several reasons, the least of which: QA will think they're always running the latest, even if they don't build the latest), and one to increment the fourth version # when you manually publish (but again, useless on multiple counts: major being that windows ignores the fourth digit) -- so is there another functionality that you speak of?

Comment: The remarks at following link is what I'm referring to, which seems a bit different from what you describe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try [ProjectBuildCounter](http://build.codeplex.com/). It is free, easy to use, no setups hassles and visual studio versions mess. Could use it for as many projects you want. You might [download nere](http://build.codeplex.com/). Usage info is [available here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuD7jpQmYck)

Comment: Your solution does not work for me.
C:\Users\..\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\..\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs goes to c:\...\Visual\..

Comment: you could try just to place the exe in the folder where AssemblyInfo.cs is located. It is fired when you run Build command from VS. Did you follow the steps described in documentation?

Comment: You solution isn't working when project is in a folder with spaces. as i said.

Comment: you should quote path with spaces as usual

Comment: I tried it ofcourse. Still Error "code -532462766" or "code 255"

now I put it in the same folder as assemblyInfo.cs now i get IndexOutOfRange exception..

Comment: please fire an issue here https://build.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic together with your assemblyinfo.cs file. Thank you

Comment: Here is a new build which I hope should fix the IndexOutOfRange - https://build.codeplex.com/releases/view/107146 As for Error "code -532462766" or "code 255" what type of projects are you trying to build? Here is an interesting post about 255 exit error code - http://www.brothersincode.com/post/Environment-Variables-and-Visual-Studio-The-command-exited-with-code-255.aspx. Hope to be in help

Comment: do you have framework 4.5 installed? It is hard to find the problem by a frase "not working". Obviously there is a problem and it will be helpful (for the other too I guess) to find it. The easiest way is to fire an issue in the  URL above with your build command line and AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: Change your entry..
        private static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args == null || !args.Any() || args[0] == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            InputInit(args);

Comment: thanks for the input Lucas. I'm little confused - obviously you've examined the code but still do not explain what is your setup and how you got Error "code -532462766" or "code 255". As for the code AFAK args cannot be null (refs: http://www.dotnetperls.com/main and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/29ff0a1f-60be-4ce5-814b-ce20f0a72ae9). My tests do not reproduce any error caused by input args. There was a bug causing IndexOutOfRange exception which I hope is now fixed. As you know for sure to fix anything there must be enough info supplied as configs, actions